# Terminal has no option to "open new tab" and no label in tabs

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

In a fresh install, I have a terminal like everyone else on the Internet, but it is a weird one for me.

Here's what my terminal looks like:

[image: My terminal]

It is missing 'user@hostname' above

Note that there's no "open in new tab" action on right click and there's no label on the tabs that show up when I "open a terminal". Also, I don't really like what the shortcut <kbd>ctrl + shift + t</kbd> does.

Why is this happening? Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu did you install ? This seems like an old version, or a particuliar flavor (like xubuntu, lubuntu,...)

Comment: What version of terminal do you have? Run `gnome-terminal --version`..

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 14.04.2 and currently using the gnome-session-fallback.

Comment: here it my output gnome-terminal --version
GNOME Terminal 3.12.3

Comment: You have the "username@hostname" portion, see `user@user-N43SM` at the terminal.....

Comment: What happens if you type `gnome-terminal` in the weird terminal?

Comment: The terminal shown is GNOME Terminal, a newer version than the one that ships in Utopic, though.

Comment: the open new tab question and username@hostname question really should be separated into two posts

Comment: I don't get it, does OP wants user@hostname in the window title or in the tab title ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This seems to be a newer version of GNOME Terminal update (>3.10). When you open the preferences dialog, you should see something like this:

[image: GNOME Terminal preferences dialog]

When you set the "open new terminals" setting to "Tab", the new terminal action will now open a new tab in the same window instead of opening a new window.

The old behaviour regarding tabs seems to have been changed in 3.12 and 3.14, for some reason.

[image: Tabs are back!… Sort of.]

You seem to have updated your GNOME components with a version that does not ship with Utopic, so you should expect to see it break.

Answer (score 5):

Encounter the same issue after upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04. It took me sometime to find the "preference" window as the solution mentioned above in Ubuntu 16.04. In case some other people have the same issue, I share the way to find the preference window. 
You can find the preferences by: open a terminal, at the terminal right top are the hidden tabs -> terminal ->Preferences

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you want the user@hostname to be in your window title, is that correct ?
For example the user bellow has dad@emachineubuntu in his window title. Is that what you wanted ?
[image]

You can set that in Profile Preferences , under Title and Command tab